# Django - link to page from template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django site, with a main page and several other pages.
How can I use django template tag to link from the main page to one of the other pages? I thought I should do it like this,

```
{% url 'contact' %}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" how? What happens? What does the rest of the template look like?

Comment: If you're having trouble linking views, you need to work through the Django tutorial. It will save you a lot of time, frustration and answer your question.

Comment: This is the error: Reverse for 'contact' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [], I am using Django CMS, and have not created any views on my own.

Comment: It sounds like you really need to go through the tutorial..  `'contact'` in your example refers to a url name in which the url then points to a view and then in return a template. Too much to cover in a simple answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. I had to add an reverse_id. In Django cms this option can be found under page > advanced settings for a particular page. Then use the template tag `{% page_url '<reverse_id_name>' %}`